# using user defined function inside forall loop

Tags: optimization, error-handling, compiler-errors, fortran, gfortran

I have a pde to solve. For optimisation, i am using forall loops and inside the loop, the variables change using a user defined function in the following way.

```
forall(i=2:n-1,j=2:n-1, w(i,j).gt.wmax/1000)
    k3(i,j)=w(i,j)+h*k(x(i),t)
end forall
```

Here, the k(x,t) is an externally defined function I defined earlier.

The error comes:

```
 Reference to impure function ‘k’ at (1) inside a FORALL block
```

I am using gfortran. What is the solution if I need a user defined function inside a forall loop? Is it possible at all inside a forall or I need to do some other thing, that also would optimise? If some other thing is possible, kindly explain that too.

Comment: As Ian says, forall will not make your code faster. If anything, it can make it slower. Just use do loops.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are referencing an impure function called k inside the FORALL block. To get this to work when you write your function you must make it a pure one, and have an interface in scope at the point you call it in the loop - pure is an assertion that the function will not (amongst other things) change its arguments, which, if this were to occur, could make parallel processing of the Forall construct give incorrect answers. If you had given a complete, minimal program showing your problem I would have shown you the changes you need to make, but as you haven't, well I can't.

But really this is by the by. DON'T use FORALL. Almost certainly your program won't run any faster than using a simple do loop, and quite possibly slower. Forall seemed like a good idea at the time, but for a variety of reasons it hasn't really worked out - I note in the latest edition of "Modern Fortran Explained" by Metcalf, Reid and Cohen, the classic book on Fortran, they mark it as obsolescent. Instead I would look into the more modern Do Concurrent, or, probably best, learn how to parallelise your loop with OpenMP.

Comment: Fortran 2018 has marked `FORALL` as obsolescent in section B.3.13.  In the discusion in this section, it is suggested that `DO CURRENT` should be used instead.

Comment: PURE or ELEMENTAL is what the function should strive for, whether it is in a FORALL, WHERE or DO loop.